# SharePoint 2013 : Event Receivers issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

In a SharePoint 2013 document library, on uploading a document the event receivers are fired in the following order `ItemAdding` --> `ItemAdded`. Likewise when re-uploading the same document `ItemUpdating` --> `ItemUpdated` are fired.

The metadata of the item is updated in the `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated` event respectively. But the Edit form dialog which pops open after document upload sometimes (intermittently) shows the old metadata (prior to `ItemAdded`/`ItemUpdated`). If the Edit form is closed without clicking on Save we can see the correct updated data in the document library. This indicated the Edit form opens up before the document metadata is updated in the `ItemAdded`/`ItemUpdated` event receiver.

Possible solutions already tried :

- Optimized the code to execute `ItemAdded`/`ItemUpdated` (decreased the occurrence of issue but did not solve).
- Added `Synchronous` tag for the `ItemAdded` and the `ItemUpdated` event receivers (no effect on the issue).
- Using `properties.AfterProperties[""]` to update values in `ItemAdding` and `ItemUpdating` but the values which need to be nulled are not reflected.

Any other suggestions to resolve this intermittent issue?

Edit 1 -

We have registered the event receiver in a declarative manner -

```
<Receiver> 
   <Name>MyEventReceiversItemAdded</Name> 
   <Type>ItemAdded</Type> 
   <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly> 
   <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class> 
   <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber> 
   <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization> 
</Receiver>
```

Edit 2 -

Elements.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="10001">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemUpdating</Name>
        <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemDeleting</Name>
        <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemCheckingIn</Name>
        <Type>ItemCheckingIn</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemCheckingOut</Name>
        <Type>ItemCheckingOut</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemUpdated</Name>
        <Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemDeleted</Name>
        <Type>ItemDeleted</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemCheckedIn</Name>
        <Type>ItemCheckedIn</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>ModelLibraryEventReceiversItemCheckedOut</Name>
        <Type>ItemCheckedOut</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an ..ed event receiver as **synchronous** *or* **asynchronous**. The behavior you describe definitely happens because your ER is asynchronous. You have to turn it into a synchronous one. This can be easily done at registration time (nothing to change in the code of the ER itself).

How do you register your ER (with XML or with C# code)? I'll explain you how to correctly change the sync/async option.

Comment: Please let me know the steps to correct change the sync/async option.

Comment: As I stated, it first depends on the way you register your ER: either declaratively or by code. Please, share your registering artifact with us.

Comment: We have registered the event receiver in a declarative manner -<Receiver>
        <Name>MyEventReceiversItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
      </Receiver>

Comment: Can you please update your question with this, for better readibility? Also, add the _complete_ element.xml file (including the parent `Receivers` node), so we can see how it is registered on lists or CT). Did you deactivate/reactivate the feature after redeploying the new WSP turned to `Synchronous`?

Comment: You element.xml looks good. Try deactivating/reactivating the feature after re-deployment. I don't see any reason this would not work here. This has been done multiple times, and that sync ER stuff usually works (one of the rare things that work well in SP! :))

Comment: Just to remind, I hope you are aware that our event receivers are firing correctly in expected order. The problem we are facing is that Edit form opens/loads before the event receivers complete their operation.  We wanted to check if we can somehow compel 'Edit form' to open/load after both event receivers finish their operation.

Comment: I got your point from the begining. I can guarantee you _synchronous_ events are made for this: be sure they're all done before anything else is started (like rendering of the `Edit` form)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the Sequence Number node. They should be in the numerical order of the sequence you wish to follow, for example:

```
 <Type>ItemAdding</Type>  
 <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly> 
 <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class> 
 <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber> 

 <Type>ItemAdded</Type> 
 <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly> 
 <Class>My.ModelLibraryEventReceivers</Class> 
 <SequenceNumber>10001</SequenceNumber>
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:
Reading further into this, the ItemAdded and ItemUpdating events are **asynchronous**. Meaning they will be queued alongside the loading of the NewForm/EditForm events. As they are both asynchronous events, the new/editform will fetch the version of the data it has to hand (the old version). Try using `SystemUpdate()` rather than `ItemUpdate()`. Also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manuj/archive/2009/09/22/itemadded-event-on-document-library-the-file-has-been-modified-by-on-error.aspx) excellent MSDN blog for reference.

Comment: The order in which event receivers are firing is fine. The problem is that the event receivers some time fires before the Edit Properties windows pops up leading to display of older or null values.

Comment: As @Evariste says above, have you deactivated/reactivated the feature after redeployment? Having ensured that **both** of your receivers are synchronous. It would be helpful to see the complete XML

Comment: Yes, the feature has been deactivated/reactivated after deployment. However that had not made any difference. Complete XML has been added in the original question (Edit 2).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to move all of your logic into your *-ing* synchronous before receivers. All updates to fields go into `properties.AfterProperties` and reference by `InternalName` of the `SPField`. Are you setting them to `null` or to `string.Empty`? I think `string.Empty` works for me.

My event receivers read properties out of office files and update SP columns based on them, including empty values clearing out the SharePoint fields.

If you cannot move the logic out of the *-ed* event receivers and setting the synchronous flag, ordering, etc does not work, I think your only option is to customize the `Edit` form to do a 'check and wait' operation. If it is only one library, you could just add a content editor web part on the edit form, extract the current item ID from the query string and do some REST calls every X seconds, query the list and check for the field values that indicate your *-ed* event completed, and then refresh/show the form once that completes.